# How to startegy.enter with % of quantity pine script

Tags: pine-script

I need to enter in deal with 5% of all balance. My code:

```
strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, qty=1000)
```

but i want something like that:

```
strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, qty=strategy.balance*0.05)
```

But there is no function strategy.balance so how can i get balance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `strategy.equity` built-in variable to figure out your equity at the moment. Then calculate your entry cash and contract size.

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, default_qty_type=strategy.cash, initial_capital=10000)

_qty = (strategy.equity * 0.05) / close

longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long, qty=_qty)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short, qty=_qty)
```